# Unable to correctly solve problem using an if statement

Tags: python

I was recently solving this problem and I’m facing an issue. I can’t seem to fulfill the hourly rate times 1.5 part. How would I solve it?
Expected output - 498.75
My output - 708.75

**3.1** Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using input to compute gross pay. Pay the hourly rate for the hours up to 40 and 1.5 times the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. Use 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should be 498.75). You should use **input** to read a string and float() to convert the string to a number. Do not worry about error checking the user input - assume the user types numbers properly.

```py
hours = input("Enter Hours:")
rate = input("Enter rate:")

# Converts to floats for multiplication
hours = float(hours)
rate = float(rate)

if hours > 40:
   overtime = rate*1.5
   total = hours*overtime
else :
    total = hours*rate
    
print(total)
```

Comment: Before trying to program this make sure you understand the algorithm. Do you know _why_ the expected output is the value it is? Can you solve it on paper? Hint: read the overtime part of the problem statement carefully.

Comment: Your post with my emphasis: "*Pay the hourly rate for the hours up to 40 and 1.5 times the hourly rate for all hours worked **above** 40 hours.*"

Comment: Hey guys! Thank you for your suggestions. Yup I have edited the message to show output instead of input.  I just noticed my issue. I pay pay 1.5 times the hourly rate for all hours,

Comment: The key lesson for you (and all programming students) is: read the question, then re-read it slowly. Almost every word is important.

Comment: For sure! Its my first time solving problems and I've started to notice that I keep on looking over small things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem says:

> Pay the hourly rate for the hours up to 40 **and 1.5 times the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours.**

Using your current code, you pay 1.5 times the hourly rate **for all hours**, not just the number of hours worked above 40 hours.

Therefore, your code should be:

```
if hours > 40:
   overtime = rate*1.5
   overtimeHours = hours - 40
   total = (40*rate) + (overtimeHours*overtime)
```

Comment: I see! Just came to that conclusion right now as well. Thanks a lot!